# Allure vs extent report for Rest Assured API testing?

Tags: automated-testing, api-testing, test-report, extent, allure

This may sound like an easy question, but it is never easy to choose (I like when I have one option).

In `API` testing I will have `20 000` test cases, and they will perform relatively fast.

Also I know, that some extent report libraries are deprecated.

Third thing is which is better for sharing the test results (report) in terms both report types are servers, that need to be running so other team members can see the results (maybe I'm not right). Which is more suitable for `CI/CD` and so on.

Anyone can down vote of course, but answer with the experience from people how are using or used both is more then a welcome.

Comment: How about asking your team about what report they want?

Comment: @pavelsaman let first consider all technical facts, and then we can consider which report is nicer :-)

Comment: it's your choice, of course. But you'll likely end up in a situation where you have x equaly viable solutions, so you'll ask your team anyway. This is not a case where technology would be a limiting factor.

Answer (score 2):

Allure doesn't allow to have single html file that you could email to someone , it requires you to spawn up a jetty local server to view the report. Where as extentreport allow you to have a single html file.

This is the only difference between the two, other than that the report generation is same in both the reports , you have to use helper methods provided by the report to add the result to the report, you does this inside listener classes.

You can zip the entire allure report and send it to team and if someone want to view it they can spawn up the local server using `allure serve`

But you can also have both the report in your framework , email the extent report for continous feedback and use allure report for detailed investigation as its more faster as it doesn't use a single html file.

Answer (score 2):

Extend Report: No CSS will be available local. If report has to be show in nice GUI internet should be there. Same to the user who is opening the report. Unless they dont have internet, you cannot see the proper data

Allure: Learning curve. will have the CSS embedded in the html

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at Test Observability - https://www.browserstack.com/test-management

Others have already called out the challenge with the HTML reports Allure generates but it also requires a fair bit of tweaking to report things in the structure you're looking for. Also, the Allure reports are one shot & static - you can't see what's changing between runs or flag out trends.

I recently tried Test Observability for my Cypress API tests (it supports a bunch of other languages & frameworks too). Worked out of the box and has a lot more functionality than Allure's static reports - some pretty nifty tools like customizable alerts and flaky test detection. The reports are all shareable, and you can even send out email notifications when your tests finish. Since you have 20000+ tests, Test Observability might be really handy in cutting down the noise for you.

Had a bunch of dashboards that break down your problem test cases as well. We've started using it to prioritize our test fixes and for leadership reporting.